# Embedding an iframe into an HTML5 Canvass

Tags: iframe, canvas

For a project i am working on i was thinking loading an iframe within an HTML5 canvass element.

Would anyone be aware of any restriction / issued involved in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load an iframe "in" the canvas. I'm assuming you mean loading the canvas in the iframe?

There should be no issues with this. Think of canvas a dynamic image.

Comment: Thanks, after some research it seems that my question indeed did no make much sense.It shoudl have read how to render HTML into Canvas element. and the answer (well one of them) would have be https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas